# pip install update says no authorization but still works

Tags: python, pip, admin

I have run these commands:
[image]
My CMD was run in admin mode and i'm the only user of this laptop (Windows 11, Python  3.10.2). It says it had an error whilst installing because it didn't have the rights (although I launched the CMD in admin) and when I re-tried it says it was already installed. am i missing something now?

Comment: what is the output of running `pip --version` in your command line? Does it match with the version of pip you want?

Comment: yes it does. didn't think of doing that. good point! Isn't it weird that I had those messages though?

Comment: Definitely a little weird. You should (theoretically) be getting output along the lines of `Successfully installed pip-22.0.3` at the end of the output from your `pip install --upgrade pip` command.

Comment: I agree, maybe it's a bug related to Windows 11? I've been told it was a bit buggy by someone else on StackOverflow (for another question).

Comment: That wouldn't surprise me. You may consider opening an issue on pip's [GitHub page](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues).